# docker file with run command not executing

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file as below and an app.docker file for php.  When I run this on my laptop everything works fine.

When I run this on my main PC the RUN command in the app.docker file does not run.  I have to CLI onto the php instance and run it manually.

Any ideas as to why?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx:1.13.12
      ports:
        - "8443:443"
        - "8080:80"
      volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
        - ./docker/nginxconf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - ./docker/ssl-cert:/etc/nginx/certs
      working_dir: /var/www
      links:
        - php
    php:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on:
          - db
        links:
            - db
        environment:
            - "DB_PORT=3306"
            - "DB_HOST=db"
    db:
        image: mariadb
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=dockerApp"
        ports:
            - "33061:3306"
```

app.docker

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mariadb-client libmcrypt4 \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && kill -USR2 1

WORKDIR /var/www
```

Comment: `I have to CLI onto the php instance and run it manually.` - what does it mean exactly? How can you run dockerfile manually in the container?

Comment: What does the logs say when you run docker compose? can you try changing the context to ./docker and the dockerfile to app.docker

Comment: @JanGaraj I have to connect to the docker image onto the command line (shell) and run the command manually without the RUN part

Comment: You can't connect to the image. Only to the container ("instance of the image").

Comment: @JanGaraj thats what I said the first time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker caches 'layers' to save repeatedly regenerating them.

`RUN` is one of the Dockerfile commands that generates layers and so Docker Engine will cache this layer and thus not re-`RUN` the command if it exists and is unchanged.

I copied your Dockerfile and built it twice. Here's the 2nd run:

```sh
docker build --rm --file=./Dockerfile --tag=59886068:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM php:7-fpm
 ---> fa37bd6db22a
Step 2/3 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mariadb-client libmcrypt4     && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql     && kill -USR2 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c76aaadf8680
Step 3/3 : WORKDIR /var/www
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fc0287d8edb2
Successfully built fc0287d8edb2
Successfully tagged 59886068:latest
```

**NB** Step #2 is `Using cache` on the 2nd build for (in my case) `c76aaadf8680`.

You can see this using:

```sh
docker image history 59886068:latest

IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY
fc0287d8edb2        21 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /var/www
c76aaadf8680        21 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…
fa37bd6db22a        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Or:

```sh
docker image ls --all | grep c76aaadf8680

<none>    <none>    c76aaadf8680        21 minutes ago      477MB
```

**NB** Your image ID will be different.

You can force `docker` and `docker-compose` to rebuild images obviating the cache with:

```sh
docker build --no-cache ...
docker-compose build --no-cache ...
```

Comment: If I make changes to the app.docker file should it not create a new layer?  As i have attempted to change the file and still get the same issue

Comment: Only if you change that `RUN` step or a prior layer-creating step. Layers are deltas and so, If a preceding step is changed or added, then the layer will need to be rebuilt.

Comment: NB a change is in a step's definition not its content. The builder doesn't check whether e.g the content of an `apt` package has changed, just the command.